# Should `predict_proba` average be population average?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, boosting

I'm running a gradient boosted tree in `sklearn` and running on some test data.  The frequency of positive examples ('1') in the test data should be around 10%, which the prediction is returning correctly.  However, if I average the predicted probabilities from `predict_proba`, I get an average of around 25%.

Shouldn't the `predict_proba` average be 10% as well?  I suppose there is nothing in the model to force this to be true; `predict` is just making a determination based on whether or not the value is greater than 50%.  Is there a way to correct for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if model outputs are calibrated, the average of `predict_proba` should be close to 10%, due to linearity of the mean.

Check out http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html for some methods to do it.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i was looking for.  Question - are Multi Layer Perceptrons well calibrated like logistic regression?  Would be intuitive that this would be so since the models are so similar.

Comment: Brief search reveals that this question is worth a paper :) according to this one https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1102351.1102430 neural networks are indeed calibrated. However according to this https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04599, calibration can be negatively impacted by some of the recent techniques.